# Анимация при появлении в DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

Как в vue.js сделать анимацию при появлении блока в dom.

Comment: как и в других случаях, либо через `keyframes` либо через `transition`

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: О_о вопрос кажется подозрительно простым. Нужно, чтобы просто при загрузке страницы, блок появлялся не сразу, а плавно всплывал?